# ConnectedService.json Environment Override

Tags: asp.net-core

In the dotnet framework you can override the Uri used by the WebReferences in the app.config or the web.config by defining a key in the appSettings section that matches the namespace that was given for the WebReference.

For the values defined in the appsettings.json you can override it's values with a appsettings.{environment}.json file.

Is there an equivalent way to override the Uri value in the ConnectedService.json file per environment?  I.e ConnectedServices.production.json